# Woocommerce - Percentage off on the sale badge php snippet does not work in the home page

Tags: php, woocommerce, percentage, code-snippets, badge

On my website choupetteland.fr I put a php snippet (see below) found on the WP Simple Hacks Youtube channel for showing percentage off on the sale badge. It works well in my category and product pages but does not work in my homepage.

Would you have an idea of the cause of the problem? I searched many topics but found nothing =/ (I saw that the sale badges on the home page do not have the same span as on the categories and product pages, I don’t know if the problem can come from there)

Thanks !

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'sale_badge_percentage', 25 );
 
function sale_badge_percentage() {
   global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_on_sale() ) return;
   if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100;
   } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = 0;
      foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
         $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );
         $price = $variation->get_regular_price();
         $sale = $variation->get_sale_price();
         if ( $price != 0 && ! empty( $sale ) ) $percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;
         if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {
            $max_percentage = $percentage;
         }
      }
   }
   if ( $max_percentage > 0 ) echo "<span class='onsale'>-" . round($max_percentage) . "%</span>"; // If you would like to show -40% off then add text after % sign 
}
```

I tried a lot of things, a lot of different snippets and I've read a lot of topics on the woocommerce sale badge subjects but nothing worked.